# Silverstripe Wont Return Field From DB

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe (Not my choice) and I'm struggling with the simplest things...

I've created a function to return some data from a table, the function works for every field in the row apart from 1, this is what i'm doing:

```
public function LotNumber() {
    return $this->LotNo;
}
```

Am I missing something, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: How does your `db` declaration look like? Maybe you're getting nothing back because the value is `0`?

Comment: Is this an example, or is this a real function? It is a little unnecessary, as $dataobject->LotNumber() would do exactly the same as $dataobject->Lotno Using it in a template environment would only return the value instead of the Dbfield object.

Answer (score 2):

Silverstripe makes use of the magic `__call()` function. Because of this, custom `getters` and `setters` may come into a little trouble (as they could be calling themselves). You can easily avoid this by choosing another method name, or put this in your getter:

```
return $this->getField('LotNo');
```

Comment: How would calling themselves be a a problem here?

Comment: With the code that is given, it would not be a problem. But he posted this because it does not work. So I concluded there might be a function with the same name (or `getLotNo`) as in his `$db` as that would give the error/notice: `Undefined property`

Answer (score 0):

First you must show more code!!!

Does `LotNo` in the some scope ?

To access to db field `LotNo` you define it static `$db` property.

**You must have:**

```
private static $db = array(
    'LotNo' => 'Type'
);
```

**Than you can access like this:**

```
public function LotNumber() {
    return $this->LotNo;
}
```